# Cloud to Device- Example for getting a ClientLogin token for the application server

Tags: android

Anyone know where I can find an example of how I can get a ClientLogin token for use in Cloud to Device messaging?  I get the general idea, but I'm not exactly sure what parameters I'm supposed to be sending, and how.

Comment: You know it's in a closed beta right now right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is [a `curl` command](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Push/C2DM/auth.sh) that generates a `ClientLogin`. It is pretty much standard Google auth, using the `ac2dm` service.

Comment: So, you don't have to pass the package name for the app or anything?

Comment: @synic: For the login, you pass `ac2dm`. For the actual push, it is driven by the registration ID. The package name of the app is already on the C2DM servers courtesy of the registration process, I presume.

Comment: Once again, you are the best.  Thanks!  Though, now that I see that on your wiki, I realize this is already in your book and I could have just read about it.  I guess I underestimate how well you keep on top of these things.

Comment: @synic: Well, I don't cover everything, but C2DM is one I happened to jump on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply it really helped me, it seems very easy. But i m really confused with what they have said over here [link](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html). What am i supposed to do, just what you said or handle CAPTCHA image and all that.. Please guide me over this.